# Calculate histogram using OpenCV's Graph API (G-API)

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to migrate an algorithm that uses a 2d histogram to run using the new G-API on OpenCV. I see that there is `equalizeHist()` available, but not `calcHist()`. Is there any way to calculate the histogram using the new Graph API?

Comment: Whats wrong with ```calcHist```? While ```equalizeHist``` working, it calculates the histogram as first step probably by using ```calcHist``` again. You wanna learn the logic of histogram calculation?

Comment: ```calcHist()``` is perfect, however I am interested in using [Graph API](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d1e/gapi.html). This is a new API in OpenCV which allows building up a graph of operations which can be compiled and executed on the GPU without having to interact with the CPU. The goal is speed. This API has most of the functions from the regular API, but notably absent is ```calcHist()```. I was wondering why, being that they implemented ```equalizeHist()``` which requires it.

Answer (score 0):

Please open an issue at OpenCV GitHub so we take this to work. Meanwhile, the API is extensible so you can add a missing operation/kernel locally (within your app): https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d25/gapi_kernel_api.html